# Trouble with CSS selector and image properties

Tags: html, css

I'm new to CSS. I have an image that I'm assigning attributes to in HTML. This is part of the code:

```
<li class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">
    <div class="user-profile user-listing" typeof="sioc:UserAccount" about="/users/chris">
<div class="user-photo">
    <div class="field field-name-field-photo field-type-image field-label-hidden">
    <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">
    <img src="Dave-web.jpg" alt="" height="150" width="200"></div></div></div>  </div>
```

I want to assign some attribute to  `<img src="Dave-web.jpg">`
through css file. I tried both of these, and they didn't work.

```
.field-item  img{
    height:150; width:200;
}
```

```
.field-item > img{
    height:150; width:200;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed that you're missing measurement unit in your css rules:

```
 height:150; /*won't work*/

height: 150px;/*works*/
```

And I hope you wanted to remove inline width and height for those images.

Comment: oops your right , i really didn't know how forget something like that ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height and width attributes from your `<img>` tag. They will override any valid css.

```
height="150" width="200"
```

Add px to your css

```
.field-item img {
  height:150px; width:200px;
}
```

Bonus: Close your `<img>` tag

```
<img src="Dave-web.jpg" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are using Drupal. You can use [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) extension and add CSS your markup items.
Also, your answer is here:

```
.field-item img {
    height:150px;
    width:200px;
    color:black;
}
.field-item > img {
    height:150px;
    width:200px;
    color:red;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7dux6d2r/)**